# Errors inserting into mySQL table using PHP (Mac)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently, I am trying to produce a bit of code to insert values into a table:

```html
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$sock = "/tmp/mysql.sock";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sock);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo ("Connection failed: ");
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (firstname, surname)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>";
}
?>
```

(some names changed) but when I run it (with the error display on!), it says this:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in /www/sites/545/473/www.example.co.uk/web/page.php on line 180

And:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /www/sites/545/473/www.example.co.uk/web/page.php on line 189
>   Error: INSERT INTO table (firstname, surname) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')

On the live page with the PHP on. I don't know why this is happening?

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: What's on line 180? It's not clear from the snippet as the `new` call appears very close to the top of this source.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that in! Line 180 is "$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $sock);". "189 is if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {".

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you read the error and look at the constructor you'll find:

```
mysqli::__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

You're sending the socket as 5th argument, while the port is the 5th argument.